# Re-sequencing an Auto_Increment column

Tags: mysql

I have an Auto_Increment column starting at 1(I already have about 100 records)
I want to re-sequence this column so that it will start at 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming id is the autoincrement column and its smallest value is 1 this should do:

```
UPDATE table SET id = 999 + id
```

Though I am not sure this is a sensible thing to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MySQL installed to test but I guess

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

should do that

Comment: no; this sets the next auto increment value, so the next record will get 1000 as auto-inc-value; it won't affect existing records

Comment: Ah I may have got the question wrong. I thought the question is user wants the first 100 records to be unchanged and wants 101st record to get id 1000 and so on.

Comment: hm... well, if it is that what he meant you got the answer right :)